# how to access docker mariadb container from outside?

Tags: macos, docker, mariadb

I followed the official guide at:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-and-using-mariadb-via-docker/
However, I haven't found any entry with bind-address in my my.cnf file, it looks like this:

```
# The MariaDB configuration file
#
# The MariaDB/MySQL tools read configuration files in the following order:
# 0. "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" symlinks to this file, reason why all the rest is read.
# 1. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf" (this file) to set global defaults,
# 2. "/etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf" to set global options.
# 3. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf" to set MariaDB-only options.
# 4. "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# If the same option is defined multiple times, the last one will apply.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# If you are new to MariaDB, check out https://mariadb.com/kb/en/basic-mariadb-articles/

#
# This group is read both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]
# Port or socket location where to connect
# port = 3306
socket = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
```

when I try to connect to it from outside, that is from the host computer, I get the following:

```
Creating a session to 'root@172.17.0.2'
MySQL Error 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.17.0.2' (60)
```

What should I do to be able to connect to the server from outside? It does run as I can connect from within the docker container.

I'm using macOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this trick `mysql -h 172.17.0.2 -u root -p` on Mac.

```
There is no docker0 bridge on macOS
Because of the way networking is implemented in Docker Desktop for Mac, you cannot see a docker0 interface on the host. This interface is actually within the virtual machine.

I cannot ping my containers
Docker Desktop for Mac can’t route traffic to containers.
```

Please see the [official docker documentation for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/).

I suggest you expose the container port to the host  `-p 127.0.0.1:3306:3306` and then connect to your DB as to the localhost `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -p -uroot`.

```
docker run --name mariadbtest \
 -p 127.0.0.1:3306:3306\
 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypass \
 -d mariadb/server:10.3 \
 --log-bin \
 --binlog-format=MIXED
```

Comment: I'd like to map the mariadb container ip afterwards under a different name, so  if I want to do the mapping.

Comment: If you need to access the container from outside you need to map the container port to the host port. MariaDB documentation suggests that you use a "hack" that doesn't work on mac but works on Linux-based systems.

Comment: @Greg please have a look at the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/)

Comment: as a matter of fact, it has worked, I used the exact commands and I can access the server. I've got another docker contaimer with a spring boot app that needs to access the mariadb at the "mariadb" host, hopefully it's going to work if I create a network for them.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration uses a `socket` for connections, as you have commented out `port`:

```
# port = 3306
socket = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

So you should uncomment `port` above (and remove / comment out the `socket` configuration). This will cause the database to listen on port 3306.

For local usage you'll want to port-map that port to localhost afterward, for example running your container with `-p` so you can connect via `localhost:3306`:

```
docker -d -p 127.0.0.1:3306:3306 [..] example/mariadb
```

Comment: still no joy, exactly the same behavour. I also tried to set the bind address to 0.0.0.0 it did not help, either

Comment: @Simon -p 3306:3306 expose the port on all interfaces. That's is not secure

Comment: @AndreiKovrov Thanks for noting that, changed my example. Greg, have you checked the MacOS firewall and similar? Do other ports / containers (for example nginx) work?